# SendInput() MouseClick have the right Position but no click

Tags: c++, winapi, input, hwnd

I have a problem and hope you have any solution for this problem! When executing from the SendInput function, the mouse is put in the right place but comically does not come a click. Did I possibly forget something?

[image]

As you can see is the button of the button was slightly lighter in the small window. (Unfortunately you can not see the mouse position in the screenshot) But I can confirm that the mouse is in the right place.

I thank you very much for your time and effort.

```
    bool ClickOnWindowPosition(HWND window, int x, int y)
{
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        cout << "ClickOnWindowPosition() parameter window is null" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;

    if (SetForegroundWindow(window))
    {
        input.mi.dx = x * (65536.0f / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN));
        input.mi.dy = y * (65536.0f / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
        input.mi.dwFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP);
        input.mi.mouseData = 0;
        input.mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
        input.mi.time = 0;

        //SetCursorPos(new_cursor_x, (new_cursor_y + windowPosForeground.bottom));

        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
    else {
        cout << "SetForegroundWindow() cant bring window in foreground" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

    int main(){
         vector<HWND> StoreWindows;
//mouseBroadCaststate called by other function

                if (mouseBroadCaststate)
            {
                //cout << GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) << endl;
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) {

                    GetCursorPos(&pos_cursor);

                    cout << "POS X:" << pos_cursor.x << "POS Y: " << pos_cursor.y << endl;


                    //Find the current Forground Window from the Store and get ClientRect data.
                    HWND hwndForegroundWindow = NULL;
                    for (int x = 0; x < StoreWindows.size(); x++)
                    {
                        if (IsWindowOnFocus(StoreWindows[x])) {
                            hwndForegroundWindow = StoreWindows[x];
                            if (!GetClientRect(StoreWindows[x], &windowPosForeground))
                            {
                                cout << "Error: GetClientRect()" << endl;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }



                    //BLOCK CODE IF NOT THE CORRECT WINDOW FIND
                    if(hwndForegroundWindow != NULL)
                    {
                    //cout << "Debug: " << windowPosForeground.bottom << endl;
                        for (int x = 0; x < StoreWindows.size(); x++)
                        {
                            if (StoreWindows[x] != NULL && GetForegroundWindow() != StoreWindows[x])
                            {

                                GetClientRect(StoreWindows[x], &windowPos);

                                //Get the new cursor position for the small windows...
                                float pos_cursor_math = (((float)pos_cursor.y / (float)windowPosForeground.bottom) * 100);

                                float posCursorSmallWindow = (((float)windowPos.bottom / 100) * pos_cursor_math);
                                long new_cursor_y = posCursorSmallWindow + windowPosForeground.bottom;

                                long new_cursor_x = pos_cursor.x / 4;


                                if (ClickOnWindowPosition(StoreWindows[x], new_cursor_x, new_cursor_y))
                        {
                            cout << "MouseClick success." << endl;
                        }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Back to the roots...
                    //SetCursorPos(pos_cursor.x, pos_cursor.y);
                    SetForegroundWindow(hwndForegroundWindow);

                    //Break the mouseBraodCast
                    mouseBroadCaststate = false;
                } //END VK_LBUTTON
            }
    }
```

> Debug:

`GetLastError()` always = 0
`SendInput()` callback = 1

I have test with only big Window (add function `ClickOnWindowPosition()`) works without problems.

Now im confused why it dont work on small window :/

Can it be that although the function `SetForegroundWindow ()` was called, that the window is not in the foreground?

I have test this i know now why is not clicked. The Function `SetForegroundWindow()` on function `ClickOnWindowPosition()` dosnt bring the window in forground. After call `SetForegroundWindow()` i test this:

```
if (GetForegroundWindow() != window)
        {
            cout << "WTF? not on Foreground?!" << endl;
        }
```

The Output is: `WTF? not on Foreground?!`

So the window are not in foreground, why :P?
The same procedure I have already used for the size adjustment. Without problems :/

Comment: Games invariably defend against fake input. As is discussed in similar questions here every day. Doubtless WOW will do so.

Comment: Yesterday it worked briefly. Therefore, I would say that this statement is wrong.

Comment: I guess the next step then is to fix all the defects in your code. Certainly your use of `SendInput` is badly broken. Don't ever send events one at a time. For a mouse click you send two events, an array of length two, first one is the mouse down, second one is the mouse up.

Comment: Does it work on other windows, like MS Paint?

Comment: I have now test with the Big Window. (code added) It works without problems. The click function works fine, only on small window not :/

Comment: #David Heffernan,  I can refuse that. ;) You can send one event for mouse click. For keyevents your answer is right.

Answer (score -2):

I think i have the fold found.

I need use `AttachThreadInput()` and use some of this functions: `SetFocus() SetActiveWindow() SetWindowPos() SetForegroundWindow()`

hope this helps others.